# Plot data in separate column

Tags: excel, vba

I have two collection of data in two separate column (column 1 and column 4). Both of the column separate by other column contain some collection of data (column 2 and 3). I just need to plot the data  in the column 4 as a function of the  data in column 1, and not the data from column 2 and 3. How to accomplish this in microsoft excel 2007?

Then, is there any way to do this with vba code?

[image]

Comment: start with [macro recorder](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/macro-recorder.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is based on Excel 2007.

If the data is fixed (i.e., additional values are not periodically added below the current data range):

1. Select the data in Column 1
2. Ctrl-select the data in Column 4
3. From the Insert tab select your favorite type of Scatter chart
4. Add titles as desired

If the data is not fixed you'll want to take advantage of [dynamic range names](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830287). Create dynamic range names for your data in Column 1 & Column 4, then modify the Chart definition to use the range names for both horizontal and vertical axes.